# microphone not workin on skype 4.3.0.37 with ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: skype, microphone

I've got a Lenovo B50-70 , it has Ubuntu 14.04.1 os .
I downloaded skype but can't make the microphone work
on it.I already tried most of the solutions I found on 
the web and nothing worked.

Please some help

Answer (score 0):

Install `PulseAudio Volume Control` ([pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)), unlock the left and right input channels, set one channel to 0%, don't allow `Skype` adjust the mixer levels.
It reduced the problem in my installation (Microphone works well with Audacity, but not with Skype).

Seems to be a problem with a ALC283.